# Laravel Forge Cannot run sudo command

Tags: laravel, passwords, root, sudo, forge

I'm using "Laravel Forge" and want to run sudo to create swap file, but it's failed because i cannot run sudo command from forge user. how to have root access or run sudo comment ?

Comment: i have this problem too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you provisioned your forge server an email was sent to you with the `SUDO` password. You can `su` or `sudo` using this password.

Comment: the problem is forge disable root authentication, so we can only login via ssh key.. is there any way forge user can run root access command ?

Comment: You don't use `root` you use `su` and you elevate yourself to perform sudo privileges as a sudo user.

Comment: ok i tried `su` or `sudo` they ask me a password, since i create server with forge, i never had any password. how to use that command without password ?

Comment: This might be old but, same issue here. Can't use `su` nor `sudo` when logging in using an SSH key that's in Forge, it's asking for a password.

Comment: @Link14 What user are you attempting to login as `forge@server`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm logging in as `forge`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Amazon lightsail with forge.

I have a pem file provided by lightsail that allows access to the `ubuntu` user which has sudo without a password.

You can ssh in as `ubuntu@<ip address>` if you have the pem file.

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/xxxxxxxxxxxx.pem ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`